# error: Error: Integer types not allowed (at 'Dimens' with value '1')

Tags: android, syntax-error

```
<resources>
    <!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">17dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">17dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="button_margin">0dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="button_size">0dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="general_weight">1</dimen>

    <dimen name="button_text_size">22.5sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="fab_margin">18dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="short_display_text_size">50dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="long_display_text_size">25dp</dimen>

</resources>
```

android studio show this
Error:(7, 5) Integer types not allowed (at 'general_weight' with value '1').

how can i manage weight properties using dimens file?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> how can i manage weight properties using dimens file?

Weight, at least as associated with `LinearLayout`, is an integer, not a dimension.

Change:

```
<dimen name="general_weight">1</dimen>
```

to:

```
<integer name="general_weight">1</integer>
```

and refer to it as `@integer/general_weight` in your `android:layout_weight` attributes.

Comment: and use `getResources().getInteger(R.integer.general_weight);` for programmatically get that `integer`